# Performing functions on multiindex in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with a MultiIndex. Here's a minimal working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'note':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'t': [0.5,0.7,1.2,0.3,0.9,1.3,1.7],'val':[1,-1,0,0,1,0,0]})
dfs = df.set_index(['note','t'])
```

which gives

```
>>> dfs
          val
note t
1    0.5    1
     0.7   -1
     1.2    0
2    0.3    0
     0.9    1
     1.3    0
     1.7    0
```

what I want is to get (a) the minimum value and (b) the first value in the `t` index per group:

```
note min  first
1    0.5  0.5
2    0.3  0.3
```

I could do a groupby on the original dataframe `df` where `note` and `t` are columns and not indices:

```
df.groupby('note').agg({'t': [min, lambda x: list(x)[0]]})
```

but I'd rather not do a `reset_index()` followed by another `set_index()` to restore the dataframe to the MultiIndex version. How do I do this? The `agg` function only works on columns and not the indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but not very clean:

```
df = (dfs.index.get_level_values(1).to_series()
         .groupby(dfs.index.get_level_values(0))
         .agg(['min', 'first']))
print (df)
      min  first
note            
1     0.5    0.5
2     0.3    0.3
```

---

```
df = dfs.reset_index('t').groupby(level=0)['t'].agg(['min', 'first'])
print (df)
      min  first
note            
1     0.5    0.5
2     0.3    0.3
```

Comment: The 2nd approach is more intuitive. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may work directly on the multiindex. Use `to_series` to convert `dfs.index` to series of multiindex and tuple values. Next, slice to get last evelemnt of the tuple values. After that just do `groupby` on `level=0` and `agg` like regular column

```
dfs.index.to_series().str[-1].groupby(level=0).agg(['min', 'first'])

Out[463]:
      min  first
note
1     0.5    0.5
2     0.3    0.3
```

Comment: Interesting approach, this also works great, thanks!